# Adding jitter to grouped boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, jitter

The following code plots the the data according to age on either the left side (Young) or the right side (Old) of each box.

```
set.seed(100)
df_data <- expand.grid(group=c("A", "B", "C", "D"), size=c("Small", "Large"), age=c("Young", "Old"), stringsAsFactors=T)
df_data <- df_data[rep(c(1:nrow(df_data)), 10),]
df_data <- cbind(df_data, value=rnorm(nrow(df_data)))

p <- ggplot(data=df_data,
            mapping=aes(x=group, y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=size),
               outlier.shape=NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(rgb(240,200,200, maxColorValue=255), rgb(198,210,233, maxColorValue=255))) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=size, color=age),
             position=position_jitterdodge()) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 16)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "red"))
```

[image]

I am looking at avoiding the separation between the black and red dots within each box, i.e. having both black and red dots "jittering" with respect to the mid-line of each box.

This is how I want the points to be distributed within each box.
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you just want `position=position_jitter()`, but presumably that's not it as you've used `position=position_jitterdodge()`. Can you explain a little more what you're aiming for?

Answer (score 0):

You could `group` in your `geom_point` based on the size to have the points jitter in each boxplot, instead of having the jitter on each boxplot within each group. You could adjust the width of the jitter points with `jitter.width` in `position_jitterdodge` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(data=df_data,
            mapping=aes(x=group, y=value)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill=size),
               outlier.shape=NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(rgb(240,200,200, maxColorValue=255), rgb(198,210,233, maxColorValue=255))) +
  geom_point(aes(shape=size, color=age, group = size),
             position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.5)) +
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(16, 16)) +
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "red"))
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: @Benoit Causalt, please see my updated answer!